# How to update very large firestore collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

I need to add a field to each document of a very large collection in Firestore via the admin sdk for node.js. Some of the documents already have the field so I need to check for its value before setting/updating it. The collection is around 150k documents. Even trying to get the documents with the code below times out.

```
  const documents = await db.collection('collectionName').get()
```

Is there a special way to handle very large collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) in order to avoid loading all the documents into memory with a single query.  This will let you process documents in batches by [specifying the last document snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) you saw in the prior query in order to make a new query to get the next page of data.

You will want to place a reasonable [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) on each query to make sure you're getting a reasonable number of documents in each page.